# A question on the Euler prime of odd perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

A number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(N)=2N$, where $\sigma=\sigma_{1}$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function.  For example, $\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=2\cdot{6}$, so that $6$ is perfect.  (Note that $6$ is even.)

It is currently unknown whether there are any odd perfect numbers.  Euler proved that an odd perfect number, if any exists, must take the form $N = q^k n^2$ where $q$ is prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  We call $q$ the *Euler prime* of the odd perfect number $N$.

In what follows, we denote the *abundancy index* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ as $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

**MOTIVATION**

Since the *non-Euler part* $n^2$ is *deficient* but *not almost perfect*, we know (from this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6767)) that
$$I(n^2) < \frac{2n^2 + D(n^2)}{n^2 + D(n^2)},$$
where $D(n^2)={2n^2}-\sigma(n^2)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $n^2$.

When the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture that $k=1$ is true, we also know that we have the lower bound
$$\frac{5}{3} \leq I(n^2),$$
whereupon we obtain, from the last two inequalities, the following lower bound
$$\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} > 2.$$
(When $k=1$, ${n^2}/D(n^2)=(q+1)/2$, so that ideally we should have ${n^2}/D(n^2) \geq 3$ since $q \geq 5$.)

From the following [Answer 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1943827/28816) and [Answer 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1942380/28816) to a related MSE question, we obtain improved upper bounds for $I(n^2)$ by successively computing the **[mediant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics))** of
$$I(n^2) = \frac{2n^2 - D(n^2)}{n^2}=I_0$$
and the upper bounds $u_i$ (for $I(n^2)$) given by
$$u_0 = \frac{2n^2 + D(n^2)}{n^2 + D(n^2)}$$
$$u_1 = \frac{\bigg(2n^2 - D(n^2)\bigg)+\bigg(2n^2 + D(n^2)\bigg)}{n^2 + \bigg(n^2 + D(n^2)\bigg)} = \frac{4n^2}{2n^2 + D(n^2)}$$
$$u_2 = \frac{\bigg(2n^2 - D(n^2)\bigg)+4n^2}{n^2 + \bigg(2n^2 + D(n^2)\bigg)}=\frac{6n^2 - D(n^2)}{3n^2 + D(n^2)}$$
$$u_3 = \frac{\bigg(2n^2 - D(n^2)\bigg)+\bigg(6n^2 - D(n^2)\bigg)}{n^2 + \bigg(3n^2 + D(n^2)\bigg)} = \frac{8n^2 - 2D(n^2)}{4n^2 + D(n^2)}$$
$$u_4 = \frac{\bigg(2n^2 - D(n^2)\bigg)+\bigg(8n^2 - 2D(n^2)\bigg)}{n^2 + \bigg(4n^2 + D(n^2)\bigg)} = \frac{10n^2 - 3D(n^2)}{5n^2 + D(n^2)}$$
$$\ldots \ldots \ldots$$
$$\ldots \ldots \ldots$$
$$\ldots \ldots \ldots$$
(That is, $u_i = \text{mediant}(u_{i-1},I_0)$.)

Note that it is easy to prove that $u_i$ (for $i=0, 1, 2, \ldots$) is a *strictly decreasing sequence*.

The resulting lower bounds for ${n^2}/D(n^2)$ (on assuming $k=1$) are:

$$u_0 : \frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} > 2$$
$$u_1 : \frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} > \frac{5}{2}$$
$$u_2 : \frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} > \frac{8}{3}$$
$$u_3 : \frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} > \frac{11}{4}$$
$$u_4 : \frac{n^2}{D(n^2)} > \frac{14}{5}$$
$$\ldots : \ldots$$

**QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Do the resulting lower bounds for ${n^2}/D(n^2)$ (using this procedure) have a closed form?
>
> **(2)** Does the lower bound ever reach $3$, or is it possible to prove that it does not?

Comment: (+1) for your effort about this unsolved problem. Recently I've seen a new  paper published by an author in arXiv on a conjecture due to you. Isn't required a response, good week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the numerators of the lower bounds form [OEIS sequence A016789](https://www.oeis.org/A016789).  Hence, the lower bounds have the closed form
$$\frac{3i + 2}{i + 1}.$$

Consequently,
$$\frac{3i + 2}{i + 1}=3-\frac{1}{i + 1},$$
so that the lower bounds never reach $3$.